# How to mock the @environment.getProperty('test.test') in thymeleaf test case

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

The code below

it is working perfectly fine in my application but I am having the test case for this thymeleaf html page as well it is throwing bean not found @envioronment.getProperty for my test case.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "@environment.getProperty('css.specific.name')" (src/main/resources/templates/test_details.html)    

EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'environment'   

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ThymesheetTestSpringContext.class})
public class ViewTest {
    @Autowired
    private ThymeleafTestEngine testEngine;

    @Autowired
    private TestMessageSource messageSource;    

    String templatePath = "src/main/resources/templates/test_details.html";    
@Test
    public void shouldDisplayVehicleInformationForIVFP() throws Exception {
        helper.assertLocalization("test", "returned", "#test");
        helper.assertLocalization("test1", "Frame number:123", "#test1");
    }
} 
   public class ThHelper {

    private ThymeleafTestEngine testEngine;
    private TestMessageSource messageSource;

.....................................
private Callable<HtmlElements> view = () -> testEngine.process(templatePath, model);

    private Function<Map<String, Object>, HtmlElements> viewWithModel = (model) -> testEngine.process(templatePath, model);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `autowire` your `Environment` bean so that it can have instantiated object like below.

```
@Autowired
Environment environment
```

You can also set `@Value` annotated fields through `ReflectionUtils` from `spring test framework`

A typical setField would look like as specified below:

```
ReflectionUtils.setField(mockedServiceWhichNeedsValueSet, nameOfFiledToBeSet, valueToBeSet);
```

Comment: Already tried the above but havent tried ReflectionUtils. I am trying to run the thymeleaf test case using thymeleaf tdd jar and it has ThymeleafTestEngine but dont know how to inject the Environment bean in this.